# Flow inheritance - class B extends A incompatible with A

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I would expect this to work and not outputting errors in flow:

```
/* @flow */

class TreeNode {
  root: TreeNode
}

class RootNode extends TreeNode {}

class OtherNode extends TreeNode {
   root: RootNode 
}
```

But instead I get: `TreeNode. This type is incompatible with RootNode`. Tho `RootNode` extends `TreeNode`

What am I doing wrong?

You can see the issue there https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCcBTUgOTgBNSwBvVMMYuOAFwC4izKbTUAX3RY8BAEpt2VWmFIAPdqQB21AiXIy69YZhz4wAeXYALUsS1zFKtT038GTZqw7dJHS0KA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fields and properties are invariant by default because you can both read and write them. You need to mark you field as covariant to allow subclasses

```
/* @flow */

class TreeNode {
  +root: TreeNode
}

class RootNode extends TreeNode {}

class OtherNode extends TreeNode {
   root: RootNode 
}
```

[Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCcBTUgOTgBNSwBvVMMAamLjgBcAuIsymqVQBfdFjwEASh05VaYUgA9OpAHbUCJcnLr1RmHPjAB5TgAtSxHQuVqNfbYIZNm7Lr2ldrI1EA). [Further reading](https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/) to get a better understanding.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I read about the `+` and `-` but thought it was just about read-only/write-only!

Comment: hmmm... now comes this issue: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCcBTUgOTgBNSwBvVMMAamLjgBcAuIsymqSZhhGOADtcnYgFcMnOMTAAKdl14lyVWgEoGw5pwAWAS1wA6NZzABeMFeEBfVM8w58YAEodO2uqQAPTlJxagJNAVoGVyw8AgB5Y1JiPzBA4NDw-lTGZnsfXm8uVJdUIA

Comment: @Huafu It is related to what you are able to do with the field. :) If you want both consume (write) and produce (read) the field has to be invariant. You might want to make your base class [parametrized](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCcBTUgOTgBNSAeABWzIDsAXK2wgPjAG9UYMMThw2ALjBNWHGqUKCwijHBa42xAK4Y2cYmAAUIsZOml2neQEp+ioWwAWAS1wA6Y2zABeYaLaKAX1QgzBx8MAAlP0swUgAPNnNqAhJySzoWTRgYXgEASBU1DW1dfQMbASEqsFxNAAdSYgNM7Ks7MCCQrDwCAHlHRpj4xJZkojJKOToosUtc4PRC9V8TSOi5bzAWUiQZ2Vpy9GBgMDgAa0xVZZhSbChJfodBjZ9tpEfng48bI5OAEgAonEGjoAcQRMRLkUwDc7gAmB4DYgxV47MAfZFyAywqBWIA)

Comment: Thanks again, I tried with parametrization of the base class, but then as I had to use the same base class in itself it was kinda recursive infinite isse:
`class A<T> { prop: T }; class B extends A<A>` which of course was issuing a problem. I'll try to have a base parameterized interface then.

Comment: Anyway - marking this as resolved since my original question as it is is resolve by your answer.
But I still land into some issues, since my tree will have nodes of any kind, but al extending `TreeNode`. So I can't really parametrize this right? or using ored types like `stuff: SomeNode | SomeOtherNode | AgainAnotherNode`?

Comment: @Huafu It is hard to say w/o knowing your requirements and programming paradigm you are writing your code with. If you are more of a OOP guy and want inheritance then you'd have to play with generics. Maybe have 2 parameters for your base class. If you prefer functional way you might not need inheritance and classes at all use algebraic data types with unions and intersections.

Comment: I like OOP but I think I am asking too much for `flow`. My Classes are quite complex and I am actually checking how/if Typescript could be a better solution overall. I am pre-processing my code with babel anyway, so using ts instead of babel will not be a blocker. I have actually now passed this particular issue, but using TypeScript instead. Will see how it goes with the rest of my code but I am globally more happy and feel that TS is way more flexible. Thanks for all your comments and help!